# How can I get the grid (under the asset) show when importing through the asset browser?

Tags: collections, asset-browser

When I drag a `collection instance` from the `asset browser` I don't see the grid that moves together with the asset (I don`t know what it is called). So I can not snap the collection to the surface. It just moves to some point in space below the scene floor.

I thought this might be because they are not `object`s but `collection`s; but I watched a tutorial (see images) the grid was there; so that shouldn`t be the reason.

[image: asset browser grid]
[image: the collection snapped to the origin grid]